# civicrm:publish

Tags: upgrade, composer

I have just updated an environment running under IIS/Windows to CiviCRM 5.69.1. It's system status is Error with
[image: System status error message]

Running

```
composer civicrm:publish
```

gives

[image: composer civicrm:publish result]

I have a similar problem on a development environment under 5.71.alpha1, where

```
composer civicrm:publish
```

does not error, but neither does it publish, so I still have the same error in the system status.

Any suggestions?

Comment: It sounds like a really old version of civicrm-asset-plugin is there. When you upgraded did you just do civicrm-core? How are you upgrading?

Comment: I solved the problem on the 5.69.1 site by running:

composer require civicrm/civicrm-asset-plugin

This updated the plugin to 1.1.4.

Running 

composer civicrm:publish

cured the issue, but I still have on my development site. This is why I haven't answered my query.

Comment: I 'solved' the problem in my development version by removing a newline from the end of  the version number string in:
<drupal root>/web/libraries/civicrm/core\js/version.json.

So it could be that composer civicrm:publish is working, but the verin number is being copied incorrectly.

Comment: The version.json was just fixed in master on the weekend, so depends how current your dev site core repo is.

Comment: Updating CiviCRM:
composer require civicrm/civicrm-core:$VERSION civicrm/civicrm-drupal-8:$VERSION civicrm/civicrm-packages:$VERSION --update-with-all-dependencies --no-update
followed by
composer update
This is because sometimes I am update Drupal as well, so combine the two into one composer update. 

I suspect the civicrm:publish repo might have been out of date.